# Footnote indentation on first page

Tags: lyx, footnotes

Using LyX. While I can remove the indentation of the footnotes on subsequent pages, with `\usepackage[flushmargin]{footmisc}`, the first footnote---really a thanks---with address information stays indented. Looking for a fix.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[flushmargin]{footmisc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}

\title{TITLE}
\author{NAME
\thanks{ADDRESS}\\ EMAIL}

\maketitle

Text

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without any additional package, you can try adding these lines in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\maketitle}{\@makefntext}{\fakecommand}{}{}
\patchcmd{\maketitle}{\rlap}{\hbox}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{\@author}{\hspace*{5pt}\@author}{}{}
\makeatother
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[flushmargin]{footmisc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\maketitle}{\@makefntext}{\fakecommand}{}{}
\patchcmd{\maketitle}{\rlap}{\hbox}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{\@author}{\hspace*{5pt}\@author}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{TITLE}
\author{NAME
\thanks{very very very very very very very very very very very very very very
very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very
very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very
very very very very very very very very very very very very very long ADDRESS}\\ EMAIL}

\maketitle

Text\footnote{very very very very very very very very very very very very very
very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very
very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very
very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long text}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

### Explanation

The command `\maketitle` redefines the commands for typesetting the footnote, so we revert this behavior.

We patch (through the command `\patchcmd` from the `etoolbox`) the `\maketitle` command so to not redefine `\@makefntext` (we let it define a new fake command `\@makefntext`):

```
\patchcmd{\maketitle}{\@makefntext}{\fakecommand}{}{}
```

Also the command `\@makefnmark` for normal footnotes is defined as

```
\def\@makefnmark{\hbox{\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}}
```

while `\maketitle` redefines it as

```
\def\@makefnmark{\rlap{\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}}
```

As you can see `\hbox` is replaced by `\rlap`, so we patch again `\maketitle` to revert this:

```
\patchcmd{\maketitle}{\rlap}{\hbox}{}{}
```

Finally we patch `\@maketitle` so that the author is printed in the right place (adjust `5pt` if it doesn't fit well)

```
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{\@author}{\hspace*{5pt}\@author}{}{}
```

Answer (score 3):

Footnotes in title are typeset differently from footnotes in the main body. To remove indentation of footnotes in the title, one could use the `titling` package.

## Code

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[flushmargin]{footmisc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{titling}
\setlength{\thanksmarkwidth}{0pt}
\thanksfootextra{\hspace*{-1em}}{}
\setlength{\thanksmargin}{0em}

\begin{document}

\title{TITLE}
\author{NAME
\thanks{Footnote in title Footnote in title Footnote in title Footnote in title Footnote in title Footnote in title Footnote in title Footnote in title Footnote in title Footnote in title Footnote in title}\\ EMAIL}

\maketitle

Text\footnote{Footnote in main body}

\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

Comment: This works, now that my `thanks` goes to the second line it is off to the left. Is it possible to adjust this code to make the entire paragraph aligned?

Comment: @ChrisJ: Does the updated answer address the alignment problem? I added `\setlength{\thanksmargin}{0em}` to justify the second and subsequent lines of the texts in `\thanks`.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not, the second line of my thank you is to the left of the first line by a half cm or so.

Comment: @ChrisJ: That's strange. Would `\setlength{\thanksmargin}{-\thanksmarkwidth}` work? If not, could you update your MWE to show the problem?